# How to update row in SQL Server with the average of previous rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, sql-update

I'm working in a database which is constantly populated with data coming from a piece of equipment. Unfortunately, in the last months, some data came wrong, filling the database with trash. In order to fix that, I need to update the wrong rows with the simple average of the last three data saved before each buggy row.

Is there a straight code to do this? I've been manually calculating and updating each row in the last hours and that isn't much productive. I know I can use UPDATE with SELECT to change the data of a row with data from another table, but how do I "pick the last three data with column id = equip_id, sum, divide by three and update where I want"? I was thinking in something like this:

```
UPDATE problem_table 
SET Col1 = problem_table_id.Col1, 
    Col2 = problem_table_id.Col2 
FROM (
    SELECT EQUIP_ID, Col1, Col2 
    FROM problem_table) problem_table_id
WHERE 
    EQUIP_ID = the_id_i_want and
    DATA_ID < curr_buggy_row
```

But that (or something like that) wouldn't have the average of last X data, but at best the last data before the buggy row's one.

Comment: [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: This might get you a good chunk of the way to where you want to go: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/02/rolling-averages-in-sql-server/ Check the example that says:  tell SQL Server that we’d like an average of st over the last 12 rows sorted by year and month.

Comment: This doesn't make sense, how is `the_id_i_want` getting populated?  or `curr_buggy_row`?  Are you asking for a solution that works on one `id` at a time?

Comment: @TabAlleman yes, that is the intend. After all the buggy rows are exporadic with wrong data without pattern. I must literally look row by row in my database to find when a trash data was inserted :/

Comment: @SeanLange I'm sorry, but your comment is unreasonable. Maybe I wasn't crystal clear in my question (I'm not even a native English speaker), but by no means, it is so outside normal questions here in SO which are also not in accordance with the manual you linked (e.g. most questions don't provide a script to create a table)

Comment: I don't think my comment was unreasonable at all. And you are correct that most questions don't have table definitions or sample data. That is why there are so many comments asking for that. Sure you may get lucky and have Luis give you an answer with nothing to work with but that doesn't mean you shouldn't provide those details in the future. If more people put in the effort to provide a working example more questions would be answered and far fewer of them closed for lacking details. Glad you got an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an option. CTEs work just like updatable views, which affect directly the underlying tables.

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT *,
    AVG( Col1) OVER( ORDER BY SomeDate ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS AVGCol1,
    AVG( Col2) OVER( ORDER BY SomeDate ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS AVGCol2
FROM problem_table
WHERE 
    EQUIP_ID = @the_id_i_want and
    DATA_ID <= @curr_buggy_row
)
UPDATE CTE 
SET Col1 = AVGCol1,
    Col2 = AVGCol2
WHERE 
    DATA_ID = curr_buggy_row;
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly! Note: I guess a comma is needed after `AVGCol1` in the SET area.

Comment: @As a complement: how do I tell this code the number of decimals I want in the updated rows? Here it's filling in with the maximum number of decimals (+10) when I only needed 6

Comment: That depends entirely on the data type. You can use CAST/CONVERT or a simple ROUND().